# this.theme = theme ?? DatePickerTheme() - How do I resolve this error in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

: Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' and 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'.
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' and 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'.
this.theme = theme ?? DatePickerTheme(),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\LE-188\Downloads\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1297
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\LE-188\Downloads\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: it is showing on your code or the package ?

Answer (score 1):

You are importing two files with the same name. Try changing the import line to:
`import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart' as AltDatePickerTheme;`

Answer (score 0):

import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide DatePickerTheme; in your main.dart file.

Hide DatePickerTheme only it will not import this from this file. So conflict will not occur.

It will resolve your issue and you can proceed further.